# Getting file path from Shiny UI (Not just directory) using browse button without uploading the file

Tags: r, shiny

I need to deal with a huge file (>500mb) in R. So instead of loading such heavy file in R environment, I process the file in chunks of specific number of rows and finally get the aggregate values.

I need user to specify the file (using some kind of browse functionality) so that I can feed the file path to my algorithm

```
fileConnection <-file( "../output/name.txt", open="w")
```

Is there any way to get only file path from Shiny UI based on the address specified by user? I tried ShinyFiles package, but it gives only directory to choose, not file.

Comment: You can use `fileInput` and use the parameter `input$inpuId$datapath` to access the datapath.

Comment: @SBista welcome back :) ...When I give fileinput, the UI actually uploads the file. I don't want the file to get uploaded (too huge and takes time). It just needs to take the path of the file. Is that possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This functionality is available in the `shinyFiles` package. Have a look at this minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
  
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    shinyFilesButton("Btn_GetFile", "Choose a file" ,
                                    title = "Please select a file:", multiple = FALSE,
                          buttonType = "default", class = NULL),
                   
              textOutput("txt_file")     
                   )

  
  server <- function(input,output,session){
    
    volumes = getVolumes()
    observe({  
    shinyFileChoose(input, "Btn_GetFile", roots = volumes, session = session)
    
    if(!is.null(input$Btn_GetFile)){
      # browser()
      file_selected<-parseFilePaths(volumes, input$Btn_GetFile)
      output$txt_file <- renderText(as.character(file_selected$datapath))
    }
  })
  }
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What if that should happen on the browser and not the server side, is there any possibility ?

Comment: @Raha due to security reasons this is not possible to get the filepath when hosted on the server.

Comment: What if I wanted to save that file name (`txt_file`) to a variable so that I could use it in a function call within my server function?

Comment: Edits that remove fluff [are fine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/6296561). Please refrain from further rollbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by shinyFiles, I developed the following file-selection modal. This removes a package dependency, allows me to control the root folder users can access, and gives me control of the file-access source code. All of which will help when discussing the app with IT/security.

##### The file-access modal as a shiny module

```r
## user interface
module_UI = function(id){
  ns = NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("button_open"), "Select file")
  )
}

## server
module_Server = function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    ns = NS(id)
    
    # path setup
    root_path = "/set/this/path/so/users/will/only/have/access/to/subfolders"
    current_path = reactiveVal()
    current_path(root_path)
    return_path = reactiveVal()
    return_path(root_path)
    
    # Selection modal
    observeEvent(input$button_open, {
      showModal(
        modalDialog(
          title = "Select a file",
          p(strong("Current path: "), textOutput(ns("current_path"), inline = TRUE)),
          fluidRow(
           column(2, actionButton(ns("button_back"), "Back")),
           column(4, selectInput(ns("dir"), label = NULL, choices = "Please select"))
          ),
          
          footer = tagList(
            modalButton("Cancel"),
            actionButton(ns("ok"), "OK")
          )
        )
      )
      new_choices = c("Please select", dir(current_path()))
      updateSelectInput(inputId = "dir", choices = new_choices)
    })
    
    # back button
    observeEvent(input$button_back, {
      if(current_path() != root_path){
        current_path(dirname(current_path()))
        new_choices = c("Please select", dir(current_path()))
        updateSelectInput(inputId = "dir", choices = new_choices)
      }
    })
    
    # OK button
    observeEvent(input$ok, {
      return_path(current_path())
      removeModal()
    })
    
    # update directory
    observeEvent(input$dir, {
      if(input$dir != "Please select"){
        current_path(file.path(current_path(), input$dir))
      }
      new_choices = c("Please select", dir(current_path()))
      updateSelectInput(inputId = "dir", choices = new_choices)
    })
    
    # display directory
    output$current_path = renderText({ current_path() })
    
    return(reactive(return_path()))
  })
}
```

##### A basic app for testing

```r
testApp = function(...){
  
  ui = fluidPage(
    module_UI("id"),
    textOutput("display")
  )
  
  server = function(input, output, session){
    selected_path = module_Server("id")
    output$display = renderText({ selected_path() })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server, ...)
}

# run app
print(testApp())
```

Note that testing of the `root_path` is recommended, because some locations can be referred to in multiple ways. For example: `dirname("~/Network-Shares/folder/subfolder")` = `"/home/ORG/username/Network-Shares/folder"`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This approach worked when running on RStudio desktop on Windows. But it fails on RStudio Server on Unix, as the `file.choose` dialog appears in the RStudio window instead of in the app.

Rather than uploading the file, we can instead just send a text string that is the file path to the app.

Consider the following minimal example:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("get", "Send file path"),
  textOutput("txt")     
)

server <- function(input,output,session){
  val = reactiveVal()
  observeEvent(input$get, {
    val(file.choose())
  })
  output$txt <- renderText(val())
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The `file.choose` dialog returns the file path of a local file. This value is passed to the app where it is stored in a `reactiveVal`. The app can now display this text string.

Note that the file chosen is local to the browser, not the server. This means that in most cases your server will not be able to access the file.

Also, important to be clear to the user that they are providing a file path, not the file. Some users will not want to share the file path for privacy or security reasons.

Comment: You might also be able to use other modal or dialog windows instead of `file.choose`, but I have not tested them.