# Using Shiny fileInput to get path only

Tags: r, shiny

I have a very large fixed width file I need to read in using my Shiny application. The way my program is currently structured is the ui.R contains a fileInput allowing the user to locate the file using the browser.

On the server side, I only capture the path to the file such as the following:

```
path2file <- reactive({
    infile <- input$path2file
    if (is.null(infile)) return(NULL)    
    infile$datapath  
})
```

A subsequent function takes that path as input and the proceeds to read in the file according to its layout specifications. This all works just fine; however when dealing with extremely large fwf files my program slows down tremendously and takes hours to get the path name of the file read in using fileInput

My suspicion is that fileInput is actually reading in the entire file and then my function only returns the datapath even though I am not explicitly reading in any file format type within the function.

My aim is to continue using the program as I have it structured now and obtain only the path to this file using my fileInput. I have found this topic on SO, and see it is a possible option.

[Getting file path from Shiny UI (Not just directory) using browse button without uploading the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945833/getting-file-path-from-shiny-ui-not-just-directory-using-browse-button-without)

However, I also aim to minimize the number of package dependencies I have; this has become a big issue and so if I MUST use an additional package I will, but I'd like to avoid that at all costs.

I experimented with this cheap trick:

```
path2file <- reactive({
    infile <- input$path2file
    if (is.null(infile)) return(NULL)    
    scan(infile$datapath, n = 1)
    infile$datapath  
})
```

Thinking that it would be a fast workaround, but it too is *extremely* slow so I suspect it too is not reading in only n = 1. So, my question is can anyone identify a way to use fileInput to allow a user to locate a file and have the server side function capture only the path and NOT read in the file or try and parse it in any way? More importantly, can this be done using functions in base R and Shiny alone without having to grab functions from other extended packages?

The above is the relevant portion of code in the server.R file and the relevant portion of code in the ui.R file is

```
fileInput('path2dor', 'Choose the DOR .txt file to format',
        accept=c('text/csv', 
        'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv')),
```

Thank you for you advice.

Comment: Could u please a small reproducible example

Comment: Added the relevant code chunk from ui.R above. Do you need a minimal working example or is what I provided enough?

Comment: If you haven't realized it already, the path  you get would be some path in your temp folder and not your actual path. Maybe you know this already but just saying in case you haven't realized. You can follow [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/xgFhudLZndI) link in case you are interested in getting the actual path and not the temporary path.

Comment: @HaroldDoran Did you get any answer to this question?

Comment: If you just want the path of the file on the browser-side, you may find https://stackoverflow.com/a/75218991/7742981 helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is not possible with `fileInput`. The reason is because 'fileInput' do not provide local path information to the server for security reasons.
With `fileInput` the user navigates through the browser on his local machine, the resulting file on the server side is the uploaded copy of the selected local once.

As an alternative you can use the `shinyFiles` package, which do navigate through the server side. This means, that you get all the paths on your local machine.

A second alternative could be a simple text input, which lets the user add a path by hand (make sure to check the path on the server side to not run into any troubles).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by others, due to security concerns shiny creates a tmp folder with all files loaded called with `fileinput`
Accordingly, you need to select all the files of interest in your folder and then call this tmp file with `...$datapath`
Note however that each element of `datapath` will include both the directory information and the corresponding file name. Accordingly, you need to trim those paths to only account for the tmp directory. This can be achieved as follows...
Assume you will create an object called `phu` which will only contain the first file in the folder (using `input$upload$datapath[1]`) you called with `fileInput("upload", NULL, buttonLabel = "Upload...", multiple = TRUE)`

```
phu<-as.character(input$upload$datapath[1])
phu<-substr(phu,1,nchar(phu)-5)
```

The second line removes the last five characters in the string. These characters are `0.txt` or whatever other extension you called in your input. The code provided only works with `.txt` files and requires the `tm` package. You can now use the object `phu` as the input directory of interest.
Finally, you need to call this output with an `output` object and print it in your `ui` this is shown with `textOutput("Pdiretory")` below.

The following example shows the entire process. Note that there are no security concerns because this temporary file and its content will be deleted at closing. Once more, the input files are `.txt` files.

```
 library(shiny)
 library(tm)
    ui <- fluidPage(
              fileInput("upload", NULL, buttonLabel = "Upload...", multiple = TRUE),
              textOutput("Pdiretory")
            )
    
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
      listdir <- eventReactive(input$upload, {
        phu<-as.character(input$upload$datapath[1])
        phu<-substr(phu,1,nchar(phu)-5)
        txt<-Corpus(DirSource(phu),readerControl = list(language = "en"))
        print(txt)
      })
      
      output$Pdiretory <- renderPrint ({
        listdir()
      })
      
    }
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```