# R/ R Shiny: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, shiny

Every time I load a .xlsx file using read_excel and pass it into a data frame (let's say named data), the column headers get "." inserted in them. For example for a .xlsx file having three columns "fruit 1", "fruit 2", "fruit 3" would become "fruit.1.", "fruit.2.", "fruit.3.". In order to remove this I would use the following code -

```
colnames(data) <- trimws(gsub("."," ",colnames(data), fixed = TRUE))
```

But using the same approach in a Shiny app where I upload the .xlsx file using a fileInput button, I am not being able to use these columns. Example -

```
fruits <- reactive({
  req(input$file)
  inFile <- input$file
  if(is.null(inFile))
    return(NULL)

  fruits<-read_excel(paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""), sheet = 1)
  
})

data <- reactive({
  req(fruits())
  data<-data.frame(fruits())
  data<- data[2:nrow(data),]
  colnames(data) <- trimws(gsub("."," ",colnames(data), fixed = TRUE))
})

if(any(is.na(data()[data()$"fruit 1" ==unique(data()$"fruit 1")[1],c("fruit 2","fruit 3")]))){
  print("There are blank fruit 2/fruit 3 names")
}else{
  print("There are no blank fruit 2/fruit 3 for the first batch")

}
```

The error I get is **Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors** for the if line. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: You can use `data()[["fruit 1"]]`.  In addition you should `return(data)` in the `reactive` i.e. `colnames(data) <- trimws(gsub("."," ",colnames(data), fixed = TRUE)); data})`

Comment: This solved my problem! Can you tell what [[]] does? I am still using $ but have returned data which solved it.

Comment: Can you help me solve this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67820333/r-r-shiny-downloading-data-tables-using-download-handler)?

Comment: It seems to be already answered.  thanks for the link though

Comment: Thank you for taking notice. A few points are still left unanswered if you want to take a look!

Comment: Can you please let the answerer know those details.  I know that he is specialized in answering shiny questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the `return` from the `reactive` block as we are not returning the original data.  The last expression is assignment to column names.

```
data <- reactive({
  req(fruits())
  data<-data.frame(fruits())
  data<- data[2:nrow(data),]
  colnames(data) <- trimws(gsub("."," ",colnames(data), fixed = TRUE))
  data
})
```

Regarding other cases, it may be better to use `[[` for subsetting instead of `$` as `$` is not general i.e. we cannot pass an object to subset

```
tmp <- data()[["fruit 1"]]
if(any(is.na(data()[ tmp==unique(tmp)[1],c("fruit 2","fruit 3")])))
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Found it really helpful