# Downloading large files using Download Handler gives error Error in .jcall: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am building an app which uploads a .xlsx file using fileInput. The app let's you make some edits to the data table and the user can download the edited data table. However while trying to download large files (12 mbs only) it throws the following error -
**Warning: Error in .jcall: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded [No stack trace available]** and it doesn't let me download the file. Rather in the saving folder the downloadhandler id "dl" is shown instead of the name of the file I have passed which in this case is "test.xlsx" as one can figure out from the code. Also nothing gets downloaded. Mind you this is just for heavier files (I have tried with files 12mb in size)

**NOTE** - I have already called **options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 200*1024^2)** in this app.
I have also used **options(java.parameters = "- Xmx1024m")** at some point in the app
The relevant server code is as follows -

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(readxl)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("file", "Import File", accept = ".xlsx"),
  DTOutput("t1"),
uiOutput("selectfile"),
 downloadButton("dl","Export to Excel")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  x <- reactiveValues()
  
  observe({
    
    xdf <- reactive({
      req(input$file)
      inFile <- input$file
      
      if(is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
      file.rename(inFile$datapath, paste0(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx"))
      read_excel(paste0(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx"),sheet = 1)
    })
    
    x$df <- as.data.frame(xdf())
  })  
  
  output$t1 <- renderDT({x$df},filter="top", class = 'hover cell-border stripe', selection = 'none',
                        editable= list(target = 'cell'), extensions= 'Buttons',
                        options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',pageLength =10,
                                       buttons = c('copy','csv','excel','pdf','print'), scrollX=TRUE),server=FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input[["t1_cell_edit"]], {
    cell <- input[["t1_cell_edit"]]
    str(cell)
    x$df <<- editData(x$df, cell)
    x$df <<- as.data.frame(x$df)
  })
 output$dl <- downloadHandler(
            filename = "test1.xlsx",
            content = function(file) {
                write.xlsx2(x$df, file, sheetName = "Sheet A", row.names = FALSE)
            }
        )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Can someone please help solve this error?

**Solution**

I have used the "writexl" library as a solution and the write_xl function works wonders! no dependencies on Java and is a life saver. **Code attached below** -

```
library(writexl)

df1 <- data.frame(name = c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria"),
                 age = c(23,41,32))
df2<- data.frame(name = c("Jack", "Bob", "Mia"),
                 age = c(27,29,22))
write_xlsx(list("sheet 1" = df1,"sheet 2" = df2), file)
```

Link to source [here](https://datatofish.com/export-dataframe-to-excel-in-r/)

Comment: Perhaps you should use write.xlsx from `openxlsx` package.  Your code works for small files.

Comment: couldn't append two or more such sheets using openxlsx