# have Rshiny app user upload image to dropbox /shiny server / google drive

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am almost done creating a survey using Rshiny. I want to create a button that will allow the user to upload an image (jpeg,tiff,png etc) to the R shiny server, Dropbox, or google drive. It seems the ***fileInput*** method only accepts documents like csv?  any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fileInput` actually allows the import of any type of files. You just need to set the argument `accept` to `NULL` or to any file extension that you accept. What you need to understand first, is that if you use `fileInput`, it will actually upload your file to the tmp folder (the path to the uploaded data is stored in `input$file$datapath`), and only then you will be able to upload your file to googledrive or to whatever cloud. A solution using `fileInput` could look like this:

```
library(googledrive)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput(inputId = "file", 
            label = "Choose file to upload",
            accept = NULL)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$file, {
    drive_upload(media = input$file$datapath,
                 name = input$file$name)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If the "double upload" is a problem for you, you can avoid this by using the package `shinyFiles`. A nice answer has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945833/getting-file-path-from-shiny-ui-not-just-directory-using-browse-button-without/42968062) and here's a way to adapt the code to address your specific problem.

```
library(googledrive)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyFilesButton("Btn_GetFile", "Choose file to upload" ,
                   title = "Please select a file:", multiple = FALSE,
                   buttonType = "default", class = NULL)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  volumes = getVolumes()
  observe({  
    shinyFileChoose(input, "Btn_GetFile", roots = volumes, session = session)
    if (!is.null(input$Btn_GetFile)){
      file_selected <- parseFilePaths(volumes, input$Btn_GetFile)
      drive_upload(media = as.character(file_selected$datapath), 
                   name = as.character(file_selected$name))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! In the shinyFiles solution you gave where is the file uploaded? and can I have it upload to which ever cloud i want within the app's code?

Comment: This shiny app works with Google Drive. When you run the shiny app for the first time, it will open up the browser and ask you to authenticate to Google Drive. Using the previous code will upload your file to the main directory of your Google Drive repository. If you want to modify this, you should specify the `path` argument in the `drive_upload` function, which is `NULL` by default.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! Last question: are the oauth tokens saved in the app or shiny server when a new user uses the app on a different machine?