# R - Uploading files from Shiny to Googledrive

Tags: r, shiny

I'm struggling in the attempt to upload user selected files from a shiny app (using shinyfiles) to google drive. I'm working on a slightly modified version of what I found here ([have Rshiny app user upload image to dropbox /shiny server / google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063470/have-rshiny-app-user-upload-image-to-dropbox-shiny-server-google-drive)). 
The original version results in an error when launched.
My version is not much better as the file itself is not found.
Is there something wrong in my code or is there something not working correctly in googledrive library?
Here it is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
library(googledrive)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyFilesButton("file", "File select", "Please select a file", multiple = TRUE),

  verbatimTextOutput ("txt_file"),
  actionButton("go","Upload to GoogleDrive")
)


server <- function(input,output,session){

  volumes = getVolumes()
  observe({  
    volumes <- c(Home = fs::path_home(), "R Installation" = R.home(), getVolumes()())
    shinyFileChoose(input, "file", roots = volumes, session = session)
    if(!is.null(input$file)){
      # browser()
      file_selected<-parseFilePaths(volumes, input$file)
      output$txt_file <- renderPrint(file_selected)


    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    file_selected <- parseFilePaths(volumes, input$file)
    drive_upload(as.character(file_selected$datapath) 
                 )
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'testmessage',
                              message = 'Thank you for clicking')
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```