# Uploading multiple files from shiny app to google drive

Tags: r, shiny

Using the advice from this previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063470/have-rshiny-app-user-upload-image-to-dropbox-shiny-server-google-drive) I was able to figure out how to upload a single file from my shiny app to a specific folder on my google drive. This worked perfectly. Unfortunately, I get the following error when I try to select and upload multiple files though. Any help is appreciated!
"Warning in if (!file.exists(media)) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning: Error in rationalize_path_name: is_string(name) is not TRUE
[No stack trace available]"

Here is minimally reproducible example below

```
library(googledrive)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput(inputId = "file", 
            label = "Choose file to upload",
            accept = NULL, 
            multiple = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$file, {
    drive_upload(media = input$file$datapath,
                 name = input$file$name,
                 path = "my_folder")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3):

To upload several files you need to iterate on each `input$file$datapath`, `input$file$name` pair:

```r
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    mapply( function(datapath, name){
        drive_upload(media = datapath,
                     name = name,
                     path = "my_folder")},
      input$file$datapath,
      input$file$name)
  })
```

Comment: That worked perfectly @HubertL, thank you so much.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am now running into a separate issue. When I run my shiny app on shinyapps.io, it deploys, but when I actually upload a file with this method I get an error. Warning: Error in : Can't get Google credentials. I did some reading here https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/auth-from-web.html which lead me to add "options(gargle_oob_default = TRUE)" to my script, but that does not seem to fix the issue. Do you know how to address this @HubertL ?

Comment: Update: Solved! I used this related article to https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html specifically the section on "Project-level OAuth cache" to resolve the issue.

Comment: Update 2: Unfortunately, it stopped working again somehow. When I go to upload a file it says. "Warning: Error in rationalize_path_name: object 'name' not found". Any thoughts @HubertL ?

Comment: I have no clue, good luck @ZachMargulies !

Comment: Figured it out! It was a simple typo in my code. This code works perfectly so thank you again.