# why my data path using fileInput changed to a /var data path itself? And how can I get the original data path back

Tags: r, shiny

When I upload an csv file using the code above, I text out the data path, but it looks wield, someone told me thats looks like an url mode data path, I just want to know how can I get back to the normal data path like /users/ziqinhe/..., since I remember it is normal path before but I don't know why it becomes like this
[image]

Here is my code:

```
library(reticulate)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("aa","input csv file ", accept = c(".csv")),
  textOutput("p"),
)
server <- function(input,output){
  output$p <- renderText({
    input$aa$datapath
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: And I used another laptop to run the code, it was fine at first, but after I went through codes tens times, the data path changes to /vars path to , and on windows laptop, it changes to something like ...\AppData\Local\Temp..., I don't know why it happens and how to stop the computer from doing this change

Comment: From the docs: `datapath` is the path to a temporary file where the uploaded data is stored. See https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/fileInput.html

Comment: @stefan Does that mean the data path of the file I upload will be /var/folders/... and I can't change that? but I remember it was like /users/ziqinhe/... at first tens times

Comment: ... maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945833/getting-file-path-from-shiny-ui-not-just-directory-using-browse-button-without could help you with solving your issue.