# How to get a folder path (not file path) in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I need to get the path of a folder, which will be selected by the user. I tried using `shinyFiles` but cant get it to work properly.
So far, this code has worked. However, I can get the path from files but not from folders.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)


ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyFilesButton("Btn_GetFile", "Choose a file" ,
                   title = "Please select a file:", multiple = FALSE,
                   buttonType = "default", class = NULL),
  
  textOutput("txt_file")     
)


server <- function(input,output,session){
  
  volumes = getVolumes()
  observe({  
    shinyFileChoose(input, "Btn_GetFile", roots = volumes, session = session)
    
    if(!is.null(input$Btn_GetFile)){
      # browser()
      file_selected<-parseFilePaths(volumes, input$Btn_GetFile)
      output$txt_file <- renderText(as.character(file_selected$datapath))
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I got it from: [Getting file path from Shiny UI (Not just directory) using browse button without uploading the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945833/getting-file-path-from-shiny-ui-not-just-directory-using-browse-button-without) but cannot answer because of reputation.

Answer (score 1):

For choosing a folder change the code to use `shinyDirButton` and `shinyDirChoose`.

Also noted that you should reference to `roots` where running users have permission to access otherwise it will throw errors. Example here is I assign `volumes = c(home = 'C:/Users/sinhn/')` for trial run on my Windows computer. You can have multiple location as named vector here.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)


ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyDirButton("Btn_GetFolder", "Choose a folder" ,
                   title = "Please select a folder:", multiple = FALSE,
                   buttonType = "default", class = NULL),
  
  textOutput("txt_file")     
)


server <- function(input,output,session){
  
  volumes = c(home = "C:/Users/sinhn/")
  observe({  
    shinyDirChoose(input, "Btn_GetFolder",
                   roots = volumes)
  })
  
  output$txt_file <- renderText({
    file_selected <- parseDirPath(roots = volumes, input$Btn_GetFolder)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: Example dir chooser]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I could solve the problem!